# Solve a Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

how would I solve the following:

$$
v_{yy} + \frac{1}{2}(y-2t)v_y + \frac{1}{2}v = 0
$$

where we treat $t$ as a constant and $v(y)$

There are no initial values.

The solution says to "integrate once" and then the equation becomes a Riccati equation.
I don't understand how the integration is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v_{yy} + \frac{1}{2}(y-2t)v_y + \frac{1}{2}v = 0$$
$$2v_{yy}  -2tv_y +yv_y+v = 0$$
$$2v_{yy}  -2tv_y +(yv)' = 0$$
Then integrate since $t$ is a constant.
$$2v_{y}  -2tv +yv = C$$